# Error Message This build of windows will expire soon

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-insider

so I have an issue where this pop-up appears every so often

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPFMc.png]

And plus, I don't get updates and can't change insider channel (became grayed out)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7wgi.png]

I have a genuine license, and I have no idea what causes this...

My winver:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVDHz.png]

Comment: Hi, I am logged in in the Windows Insider account, what do you mean by Microsoft Live?

Comment: The issue is persistent for a couple of months now :D
So I restarted, tried multiple commands, tried installing the cumulative patch for the correct version, but it says that it is not compatible with the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a genuine license, and I have no idea what causes this

You are using an outdated Insider Preview build from July 5th 2020.  The only solution to this problem is to update your system.

The simplest solution to resolve your inability to update your system is to manually upgrade to 20H1 ahead of its release.

You can download the [Windows 10 Client Insider Preview - Build 19043 English](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewiso?wa=wsignin1.0) ISO by selecting Insider Preview Beta Channel when presented the option to do so.

Once you are on build 19043, which is the build 20H1 will be released as, you can exit the Insider Preview build or opt to continue to receive the updates from your chosen Channel.  Your inability to change your channel is due the fact your build already expired in January.

I personally have used this method to exit the Insider Preview program more than a dozen times.

It only is possible since your current build number is lower than the final build number of 20H1 otherwise you would be unable to revert back to a permanent installation of Windows 10 without reinstalling or upgrading to the current Developer channel Insider Preview build.

Comment: That actually helped to get rid of the message, I still can't change the channel, but that's a detail compared to the main issue. So thanks!

Comment: “But if you've installed a build in the Dev Channel, because it's not tied to a specific release, you'll have to do a clean install of Windows and reset your Windows Insider settings on that device to switch.” - Unfortunately, if you are in the developer channel, there might not be a way to exit it like I thought.  In the case of past, when I performed what I described, I must have been in the beta channel. However, I suspect if you were to use an actual 21H1 ISO you might be able to exit the Insider Preview program and get normal updates without a clean install

Comment: I installed the dev channel iso, but when I do a winver, it is still on 2004, but the watermark show the same version as in the iso (21286)